# Mods, please unlock this question

Tags: discussion

A user [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020263/loading-swift-nib-via-class-not-string), which I edited into a question. Between the time I could write up my answer and post it, some bickering broke out over in the comments on a non-answer posted by the OP and the question was locked. Please unlock it.

I've got a valid answer.

---

According to the documentation, you actually *can* load a nib based view controller without naming it exactly the same thing. You're almost right, but there's a second case, which should work even with Swift:

> If you use a nib file to store your view controller's view, it is recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when initializing your view controller. However, if you do not specify a nib name, and do not override the loadView method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with one of the following names:

If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in MyView.nib.

It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

Comment: Or, just post a self-answered question instead. What's the point in polising that..?

Comment: Not a bad idea.

Comment: It should probably have been deleted rather than locked IMHO. But I'm no expert in that domain.

Comment: Related meta-rant: [Why do these mods edit my question, if they can't edit them accurately](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315490/why-do-these-mods-edit-my-question-if-they-cant-edit-them-accurately)

Comment: @PaulRoub ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Isn't this what flagging is for?

Comment: I flagged but because the question was locked and I edited my previous flag was rejected. The site gave me a hard time flagging again.

Comment: @Moshe the SOCVR room helped a bit to get that question re-open-ed. Now go post your answer ;) I assume you'll re-edit the question as well?

Comment: Thank you, @rene, I've posted an answer. The edit isn't really necessary.  Link to the SOCVR chat, please?

Comment: here you go: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28373959#28373959

Comment: @Cerbrus: Because if he did he would be accused of intentionally duplicating someone else's question just to post a self-answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's now unlocked. I hope I don't regret doing so, based on the other Meta question.

Comment: I think @cerbrus suggestion would've worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks - I'd been hoping that 1 hour would be sufficient for a cool-off but not scupper the long term chances for the question

Comment: Thank you. Still on hold, but I guess it'll rectify itself.

Comment: The linked question is at `-9/+5`, at the moment. Maybe a fresh question would've been a better idea, since this one got a bit of a unfair disadvantage.