# Why do these mods edit my question, if they can't edit them accurately?

Tags: discussion, meta

[How to load a View Controller SubClass with a nib without specifying the nib name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020263/loading-swift-nib-via-class-not-string/)

If you observe the edit history of this question, it was edited almost immediately to mean something completely different than what I was asking. And it had multiple typos.

Name one other forum where the mods have full control to edit the meaning of any post they want. It disrespects me when they slap their users around and don't bother to explain.

EDIT: You all individually don't understand my argument. I don't want help answering the question. I want to answer my own question so that others can find the answer easier. But if anyone tries to change my question, it won't be clear to the real people who are searching for my question. I now understand that anyone can edit, that doesn't make it better. The people who run this website are the people voting for themselves, its not even funny when the mod in question answers the Meta question. You can dislike it all you want, but it's not fair to new or old users to quickly demote their ideas as "kinda off topic but still unclear, please revise until we deem it perfect for our society".

EDIT 2: The users in question are @Moshe, @mah, @Flexo. @Moshe edited my first question in an attempt to fix it, but the question was changed by accident. @mah commented on my answer to the question, claiming I asked it poorly. @Flexo closed it after I asked @mah why he commented about in the first place? I would like to handle situations like that a little more privately.

Comment: SO isn't a forum.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315488/224988

Comment: "This is more of a complaint." Then it's off topic.  Don't post off topic stuff and you won't have any problems.

Comment: It's not just moderators that have edit ability, it's a community powered system

Comment: You have full control to rollback any edits to your own questions.

Comment: 1) No mod edited your poorly-written-question, 2)The user actually made your off-topic rant into a question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan He exercised that right, and the post ended up being locked by a mod, because he was rolling back beneficial edits.  You do not have the right to make your own post worse.  If you honestly feel an edit is harmful, you can revert it, but reverting helpful edits just because you don't want your posts edited won't turn out well for you.

Comment: If you'd like to file a bug report or request an enhancement to Apple's developer tools, go here: http://bugreport.apple.com . If you wish to provide feedback about their products, go here: https://devforums.apple.com . Apple engineers don't read SO questions looking for bug reports, so aside from the cathartic nature of yelling about this into the void, there's little to gain by posting them here.

Comment: Again, we are discussing in a group on a public webpage, it's a forum. I edited it to fix the question that was edited into a different question by @Moshe

Comment: *I don't want help answering the question.* - That doesn't matter. You have to ask the question as if you're looking to get answers, even when you self answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a forum in the _most general sense._ However, Stack Overflow is _not_ a forum as it is known elsewhere on the internet. We have specific rules on what can and cannot be posted on the site and in what forms, how the content that _is_ posted should be moderated, and how content that's posted _and is against the rules_ should be moderated. You should check out the [help] for information on what can and cannot be asked on Stack Overflow, and the [ask] page for tips on how to make your original question fit the guidelines. (Since you say it's not the same as the edited question.)

Comment: I understand this @Kendra, I take issue with the way it is handled, and the people who are enforcing their own rules. The second my post was "semi-off-topic", I got burned at the stake. Then when the mod told me to take my discussion to Meta, I get burned again.

Comment: Maybe if you had actually made your original post an actual question we wouldn't be here @benjaminhallock

Comment: @benjaminhallock "people who are enforcing their own rules" No, people are enforcing *the rules of the site*.

Comment: The people who answered this post are the ones who moderated my original post. I attempted to fix my original question after it was edited poorly by @Moshe. Then other users commented on topics unrelated to the question. Then my original question was closed. Tell me how I'm not the victim.

Comment: Victim of what?

Comment: What I'm saying, @benjaminhallock, is you can make your question conform to the rules just fine. The only rules being enforced are the ones the community as a whole has agreed on. If you feel a specific rule isn't working, you can take action: Search Meta for previous discussions of the specific rule (guarantee you'll find at least one); search Meta Stack Exchange as well; if you can _improve_ on those previous discussions with examples and data then feel free to draft up a calm, well-written post on the subject; and be open to the other opinions you're going to get on the matter. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) If you can do that, and present good, hard evidence that it's not working (and remember that one data point does not good evidence make) and how to _fix it_ then you can get things on the road to changing the specific rule. But I would _start_ by making sure you understand why the rule is there, what it's for, and why _we_ think it works. But that all starts at the help center.

Comment: @benjaminhallock don't wrap up everyone in the same thing here.... the ONLY person who edited your post is Moshe. There are other comments than his here. And Flexo locked your post because of the rollback war situation. There is plenty of feedback here BESIDES theirs.

Comment: And as a quick added note: You may not have wanted help getting an answer, but Moshe was also trying to help keep your post on the site. If your question is deleted for not following the rules of the site, how is it supposed to help anyone? (It's an admirable cause, wanting to make sure others can find the answer to their problem, and we want to have a repository of high quality answers to programming problems. You've got the right goal, and you've been linked to the resources to use the complete right method. You're on your way there.)

Comment: @benjaminhallock how would situations like that be handled "privately"? and why should they? You are currently already wondering if the actions were okay,.... if it then is done privately, EVERYONE will start questioning what's happening "behind the scene". Everything is done publicly because the community should be able to see it and say if it isn't okay.... like you did here.... you want it private, but when you have a grievance, you air it publicly? I sincerely don't follow there...

Comment: @Patrice Hello, let me explain my suggestion. What I said was what has already happened in the question, but the comments got in the way of the real question. Instead of closing the question, why not just silence the comments, and help revise the question, then un-silence the comments when everything is stable.

Comment: @benjaminhallock silence the comment and help revise? What if Flexo doesn't know enough about the technologies to help out? He'll let the community handle it. How does the community handle it? Edits and comments.... Anyway, Flexo never closed your question. He LOCKED it, so the edits would stop while the situation calms down... which is similar to what you're asking... no?

Comment: @Patrice No I am asking to stop the comments, because those are what started the off-topic conversation. The question was still unclear when it was locked, so I couldn't do anything to help it be more clear. I just witnessed my question get changed over and over until I couldn't recognize it.

Comment: @Patrice Also the original off-topic comments got deleted the moment it was locked. I don't even have proof as to why it was locked in the first place. Then it got rebranded as "off-topic" question.

Comment: @benjaminhallock honestly, is it possible (I'm genuinely trying to help you out here) you're a bit angry and need to cool off a bit? On one hand, you say "silence the comment", then you continue with "but the comments were deleted". I have trouble following WHAT you're disputing shouldn't have been done, as you are all over the place (maybe I'm interpreting it all in a different way you intended it as well). Your issue is with what? The editing, the comments, the lock, the closure? What should have been done instead, and why would Stack as a whole benefit from that new way of acting?

Comment: @Patrice Well if this thread is any indication, someone is angry. I made my suggestion as clear as possible. Silencing means freezing the comments so that no one can add anymore. That should be done, instead of closing a question that was not even asked fully. If you can't help, then please don't reply.

Comment: Hey @benjaminhallock, I apologize for upsetting you. I tried my best to act within the spirit of Stack Overflow, editing what didn't look like a question into something that could stick around based on community rules. I didn't mean to be pushy or off-putting. I just posted an answer which might be relevant, but if you meant to self-answer, by all means, feel free to.

Comment: Patrice actually is trying to help, it's just that you seem to be pointing at different things that you feel were handled incorrectly, which makes it hard to address and help come up with suggestions/solutions. By the way, locking the question as Flexo did _does_ prevent more comments. The comments were probably then cleared as irrelevant or out of hand, one or the other. The reason for the lock was actually in the lock message (in this case, it was due to the editing back and forth) though sometimes those banners aren't the clearest. On the plus side, your question's reopened.

Comment: As an aside, I up-voted the original question now that it's... a question. :)

Comment: @Kendra thx for seeing it. I went ahead and re-read everything because I somehow feel the "someone is angry" is directed at me.... and I really fail to see how this could be taken from my messages... *shrugs*

Comment: @Patrice No just please stop replying and taking this personally.

Comment: @Moshe I also apologize, thank you for teaching me my error.

Comment: @Kendra Yes, but if you read my suggestions, I say I want comments to not be deleted after being locked.

Comment: Well, that can be a problem. Sometimes they don't delete the comments if they lock a post. But comments are considered second class citizens on Stack Overflow- If they aren't adding anything to the post, there's a good chance they'll be deleted. If they are... Whatever they're adding should be edited into the post. So if the comments were irrelevant to improving the question, or if they were hostile (or just agitated), mods don't think twice about just clearing the thread. But that would be a new Meta topic, to discuss that. (If you go for a new discussion, please check for duplicates first.)

Comment: @Kendra I understand, I will open a new topic to discuss the change.

Comment: Sounds good! Just, like I said, _please_ check for dupes first. And be sure to do some research first so you can have a well-defined suggestion, or at least have a decent idea of how it would work to be discussed. This will help lead to a more open and constructive discussion of your idea. (I've seen a lot of discussions on Meta go down in flame due to dupes/lack of supporting material or research/bad or ranty tone/etc.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like you have an incomplete understanding of how Stack Overflow works, specifically regarding editing.

Your question isn't being edited by "mods", in the sense that a post on a forum might be. Rather, on Stack Overflow, any user with editing privileges can edit posts regardless of who wrote them. It's every user's responsibility to help ensure a high quality of clear and useful content on the site. In its original form, your post did not contain a question that met the guidelines for what is appropriate on Stack Overflow. As such, someone edited it to help ensure it met the requirements for high-quality Q&A content.

For more information, I'd highly encourage you to read through the Help Center, in particular the following post (thanks, commenters!) which will help understand what's expected of questions on Stack Overflow:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

  I'd also recommend looking over these posts on Meta Stack Exchange to understand edits:
- [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)
- [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer)

You'll have a much happier time here once you understand the unique differences between Stack Overflow and other resources such as web forums with which you may be familiar.

Answer (score 27):

Everything needs to be a question or an answer to a question here on Stack Overflow. We like (and encourage) self-answered questions, but they have to stick to that core format still

A user (note: not a moderator) edited your question to make it into an actual question that fits the format of the site, instead of merely voting to close, which would have ended up happening. They did that out of good intentions as far as I can see, entirely within the spirit of the intention of the edit privilege. I'm not a subject matter expert for this particular question, but to the best of my knowledge it still reflects the same underlying problem.

There's no abuse here.

You subsequently responded by reverting their edit and adding further text to the question which didn't form part of the question, but instead started a meta-discussion about moderators, edits and policy.

The help centre states:

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

which seems to directly apply here.

The choice seemed to be between your question getting closed, or shaping it up to be a question. That someone gave their time to improve things seems to be the opposite of disrespect.

Comment: It's not fair when the mods in question are the ones who answer the question about themselves.

Comment: @benjaminhallock A moderator didn't edit your question. A user with editing privileges did. You can tell the different by the `♦` at the end of a moderator's name. The only think moderators did was lock the post when an edit war started.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Did I say the word edit? Flexo is the one who closed it, that makes them apart of this case.

Comment: @benjaminhallock I did not close it, I applied a 1 hour, temporary lock with a view to de-escalating what was an active edit war and on-going conversation inappropriately taking the form of comments when I became aware of the post. I answered your question here and indeed alerted you to this mechanism for requesting review and oversight because I believe in accountability for my actions. I can only achieve that by answering criticisms directed at me. I deliberately haven't prevented or in anyway touched any other feedback you've received from the community, simply outlined my observations.

Comment: @Flexo But you can agree, those off-topic comments have been removed from public. If you look at the record of those comments, I did not write the first comment. The other mod known as mah had equal blame.

Answer (score 25):

I don't see how the edit changed the meaning of the post at all.  It removed noise that didn't belong there, and made the important points of the question stand out a bit better.

When you noticed the typos you should have *just fixed them*.  The edit was pretty clearly, on the whole, a net benefit, and the small mistake can easily be rectified.

> Name one other forum where the mods have full control to edit the meaning of any post they want.

I've never known of one that didn't.  Generally having the ability to edit a post is essential for a mod to do their job.

Having said that, SO (and SE as a whole) is unique in that not only can mods edit posts, *any user on the site* can edit any post.  It's one of the tools of the site here to improve the quality of the content here.  There are of course certain types of things that are and are not supposed to be done when editing a post; I see nothing in the edits here (by users other than you) that isn't an appropriate use of the editing system.

> It disrespects me when they slap their users around and don't bother to explain.

I fail to see what's disrespectful in improving your question.  I also don't really see why such improvement really needs explanation.  If you really wanted it though, you could have simply asked, politely, why the edit was made, or politely explained why you felt it wasn't an improvement.  Your completely unconstructive response was not appropriate.

Comment: The question I was asking was changed from a Nib based discussion to a storyboard based discussion. Two very different things in iOS. I simply edited my question back to it's original intent while improving the structure, and then it was closed.

Comment: @benjaminhallock - *changed from a Nib based discussion to a storyboard based discussion* - I think it would have helped things drastically if your original meta post had said this.

Comment: Well I assumed you read the edit history. That's where the proof of that change is.

Comment: @benjaminhallock And yet dozens of people have read your question at this point, and felt that the edit wasn't changing the meaning of the question.  All because you couldn't be bothered to explain what about the meaning of the question was changed.

Comment: @benjaminhallock: if you didn't want your post corrected, then it should have been quickly down-voted, closed and deleted. Period. As written it did not meet the standards of this site.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with my second revision.

Comment: @benjaminhallock: Having others edit your posts to fix things you had not considered needed fixing can be a bit rough on the ego, but Stack Overflow is about helping as many as possible, and the attitude of users here needs to be to give — and accept! — help as graciously as possible. I've personally edited posts by even ♦ moderators on multiple occasions, often because they misspelled something… but occasionally even because of a more serious error in their posts. That's the intended model, where even the most senior can be corrected if they post something that needs more work.

Comment: @benjaminhallock: "*The question I was asking was changed from a Nib based discussion to a storyboard based discussion.*" Even if that's true of the first change, that was still *only* the first change. Once your first edit removed all talk of storyboards, *nobody added them back*. So I don't buy that there was any shift to a "storyboard based discussion". At *best*, there was a momentary one, which Moshe did not attempt to add back in with his second edit.

Comment: @NicolBolas In an attempt to fix my post, there was an equally confusing edited post made. That was the issue. Then it spiraled into off-topic. The question was closed before I could refine it to it's final state.

Comment: @benjaminhallock `The question was closed before I could refine it to it's final state.` That's *the point of closing questions.  When a question isn't yet in a good state questions are closed *so that the problems with them can be fixed*, at which point they can be reopened.

Comment: @Servy When a question is closed, it cannot be edited by the owner.

Comment: @benjaminhallock Wrong; when a question is closed, [it most certainly can be edited](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).  When it is locked, no one can touch it.

Comment: @Daedalus Okay, then if you check the history, it was locked first. not closed.

Comment: @benjaminhallock You're the one that said closed.  I was just clarifying that a closed question can indeed be edited.

Comment: @Daedalus Well pardon me.